# Buttons in a simple popover

Tags: ios, uibutton, uipopovercontroller

I'm trying to achieve this kind of popover:

[image: popover]

The problem is, simply using RoundRectButtons don't seem to give the same effect (borders are ugly and text is blueish). **How are these buttons done?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that's a UIActionSheet, being displayed as a popover (which is how action sheets are displayed in iPad). If you create one of those, you get the button styles for free.

Comment: woah I didn't even have to create the view, I just created a new UIActionSheet on the code and called its "show" method. Nice! thx